# ボタンが押されたらpythonスクリプトを実行

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sh

タイトルの通りボタンが押されたらpythonスクリプトが実行されるようにしようと思い
以下のスクリプトを作成しました

```
#!/bin/sh
GPIO=22     #使用するGPIOポート
PUSHTIME=5  #押す秒数

#初期設定
echo "$GPIO" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$GPIO/direction
echo "low" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$GPIO/direction

#5秒間押されるまで待つ
cnt=0
while [ $cnt -lt $PUSHTIME ] ; do
  data=`cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio$GPIO/value`
  if [ "$data" -eq "1" ] ; then
    cnt=`expr $cnt + 1`
  else
    cnt=0
  fi
  sleep 1
done

#dialogue_test.pyの実行
python dialogue_test.py
```

しかしボタンを押してもpythonスクリプトは実行されていないようです
詳細
最後の行”python dialogue_test.py”をシャットダウンコマンドに変えると
正常にシャットダウンします
またdialogue_test.pyは正常に動作します
環境はraspberry pi 2 です
参考サイトは[Raspberry Piに電源スイッチを付けたくてシェルクスリプトについて少し調べた話](http://engineernote.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/03/10/013210)

どうすればいいでしょうか

Comment: 少なくとも`dialogue_test.py`を絶対パスで指定してやる必要があるかと思います。

Comment: 分かりました。ありがとうございます